# How to display different articles using PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem and I can't find information about this, I'm newbie in PHP and I need help if anyone can help...

So here is my problem, I want to display different articles on page, I have in MYSQL created articles and when I try to display all of them I'm getting same articles with same names all the time, when I change ID number from tab bar I can see different article but names are changed and still they are all same with same href.

```
<nav class="sdb_holder">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $rsNews['id'];?>"><?php echo $rsNews['name']; ?></a></td>
      <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $rsNews['id'];?>"><?php echo $rsNews['name']; ?></a></td>
      <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $rsNews['id'];?>"><?php echo $rsNews['name']; ?></a></td>
      <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $rsNews['id'];?>"><?php echo $rsNews['name']; ?></a></td>
      <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $rsNews['id'];?>"><?php echo $rsNews['name']; ?></a></td>
      <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $rsNews['id'];?>"><?php echo $rsNews['name']; ?></a></td>
      <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $rsNews['id'];?>"><?php echo $rsNews['name']; ?></a></td>
    </tr>
  </nav>
```

php code:

```
$db = mysql_select_db("db"); 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
 $id = $_GET["id"];
}
else{ 
$id="1"; 
} 
$news_sql = " SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = $id"; 
$news_query = mysql_query($news_sql); 
$rsNews = mysql_fetch_assoc($news_query); 
?>
```

Any help?

Comment: where is your `php code`?

Comment: you mean this? $db = mysql_select_db("db"); 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = $_GET["id"];}else{
 $id="1";
}
$news_sql = " SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = $id";
$news_query = mysql_query($news_sql);
$rsNews = mysql_fetch_assoc($news_query);

?>

Comment: stop using MySQL_* functions! http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/3664960 If you're a newbie it's best to start looking into a newer tutorial that explains PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Thank you for your advice! appreciate it but I have to finish this till the morning and I don't have time to check and learn how to do it with newer version, that's why I decided to ask for help here... I'll use and learn PDO or MySQLi but now if you can, please help me  to fix this... Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know for sure, because other parts of your script seems to be missing, but I think what you need is this:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_select_db("db"); 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
    $id = $_GET["id"];
}
else{ 
    $id="1"; 
} 

//fetching the register based on your id.
$news_sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = $id"; 
$news_query = mysql_query($news_sql); 
$rsNews = mysql_fetch_assoc($news_query);

//faching all other records in your db.
$all_news_sql = "SELECT * FROM news"; 
$all_news_query = mysql_query($all_news_sql); 
?>
```

I've created another query, to fetch all your other posts in database. You were aways trying to display the same post fetched with same ID. That's why you had same names.

Here comes the part where you display all other records:

```
<nav class="sdb_holder">
    <tr>
      <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_news_query)): ?>
          <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
      <?php endwhile ?>
    </tr>
</nav>
```

You don't need to repeat your code to show all records, because sometimes you don't even know how much records you have in your database. That's why we put the code only once, inside while loop, so it will repeat until retrieve the last record in my query.

I think that's it. I understand you're in a hurry for tomorrow, but when able, consider changing the mysql functions to PDO/Mysqli.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: You are awesome ! Thank you so much! It is working now!

Comment: And yes, I'm going to start changing mysql to PDO/Mysqli after this project :) Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to know it's working =) Mark the answer as correct when able =D

Comment: It is working but now I have other issue and can you take a look at this please? when I use your code getting doubled article names

Comment: <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $rsNews['id'];?>"><?php echo $rsNews['name']; ?></a></td>
            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_news_query)): ?>
          <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
          <td><a href="news.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
          <?php endwhile ?> this is a code how I use it and this is an image how it looks like: http://prntscr.com/ekww73

Comment: I think it's because you've repeated the line that shows the record: Look this image: https://i.imgur.com/4uJoeSy.png  Remove one of them and try again.